# What is the proper location for scipy installation on Mac 10.8 with homebrew Python?

Tags: python, macos, scipy

I followed the advice of most pythonistas and set up a different version of Python with which to play than the one that comes built into Mac OS X. After scanning around, it seemed like the best way to handle things was to use `homebrew`, and then to follow up with `pip`. All was good up through `numpy`, and then things went bad. I can't get `scipy` to install nor `matplotlib`. After searching here at StackOverflow and trying a number of solutions, I finally stumbled across Chris Fonnesbeck's ["Scipy Superpack"](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/), which promises to:

> install recent 64-bit builds of Numpy (1.8) and Scipy (0.12), Matplotlib (1.3), iPython (0.14), Pandas (0.10), Statsmodels (0.5.0), Scikit-Learn 0.13, as well as PyMC (2.2) for OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) on Intel Macintosh.

That all sounds great to my noobie ears, but when I look at the install script, `install_superpack.sh`, it seems to be directing things to work with the system's version of python:

```
#!/bin/sh
PYTHON='/usr/bin/python'
GIT_FILENAME='git-1.7.7.3-intel-universal-snow-leopard'
GIT_VOLUME='/Volumes/Git 1.7.7.3 Snow Leopard Intel Universal/'
GFORTRAN='gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg'
SUDO='sudo'
```

Should I change the `PYTHON` variable above or leave it be and make adjustments to the PYTHON ENVIRONMENT (yes?! No!?) thingamabob I have read about elsewhere? What else, if anything, should I edit? Or should I just back away from this script since I clearly am out of my depth?

I should note that I would dearly love to get `matplotlib` running on my machine because I'd like to play with making histograms for some text analysis I am pursuing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The superpack was compiled for the Apple python. It might work with your python from homebrew, but it's not recommended.

And by the way, when you say:

> it seemed like the best way to handle things was to use homebrew, and then to follow up with pip

If this was true, then there wouldn't be a ton of questions here of people having trouble installing scipy with homebrew/pip. Homebrew and pip are great for minimalistic, pure python packages. But they stumble spectacularly with scipy or packages that require external non-python packages.

With Macports now having a buildbot for OSX 10.8, I personally see no reason why anyone would want to bother with homebrew/pip for a scientific python install. With a good internet connection it will take minutes to install a full setup, and you can have matplotlib with as many backends as you want.

Comment: I used to use MacPorts for some other custom installs. I gave it up because of some difficulties I encountered and because of a number of recommendations for `homebrew` at the time. That noted, I'm happy to go back to MacPorts if it solves all these issues. At this point, I just want a working setup so I can get to work. Many thanks. I'll give this a try this morning and if it solves it, yours is the answer.

Comment: I'm just going to leave a bit of documentation here, in case anyone else lands on this page with similar difficulties. Following tiago's answer, I first [uninstalled home-brew](https://gist.github.com/1173223) -- link is to a `gist`. After that, I headed over to the [Macports install page](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and picked up the installer for Mountain Lion.

Comment: Okay, a few interruptions later and I can confirm that tiago's answer is correct, but there are a few steps, most of which are simply a matter of follows MacPorts directions -- install MacPorts, then install Python, then install numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc. The reall critical part is making sure you also install `python_select`. I was not able to steer my setup to the correct Python, here the MacPorts version, using `.bash_profile.` I was, however, able to do so using this little utility.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working in the end. Usually in the in the install, MacPorts will print out the `python_select` command that you should enter to select the version that you want. Otherwise it will be installed, but utilities will be called python2.7, ipython-2.7, and so on. There is also the issue of the infinite combinations of variants. I found that lately the default ones work very well. I usually try and steer clear of having to install X, Latex (mactex is better), and make sure it uses PySide instead of PyQt4.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think I got the `python_select` command but I kept a copy of everything so I could go back over it -- and also to make sure I can document these steps for myself, so when I have to repeat this on my work machine, I can. I'll see if I missed it. I already had xQuartz on this machine, for another purpose, but it doesn't appear that anything I am doing is going to require it. I installed MacTeX for another project I am working on, so I think I may actually be good to go. Thanks for point me to MacPorts. It's very nice to see things simply work.

Comment: It will do a print out and say something like "please run this command to select the python version". About MacTeX: just make sure you don't set the `latex` variant for matplotlib (even if you do want to have latex support), because that will make MacPorts install a complete TeX distribution. Matplotlib will work fine with the latex from MacTeX, without any extra configuration needed.